# Node js post request without refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, directory

Is it possible to complete a post request without redirecting or refreshing the page?

I am  making a simple file browser in browser.
The client side shows the USB stick content of the server. You know, when I open a folder, I send a string to server with the path data, so the server can send me the current folder's content. It is very disturbing that whenever I open a folder (click on that), the page is refreshing. Any ideas?

Comment: It's called AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make an AJAX request which fires when you open the folder, the page will not refresh. You can set up a route on your server that will handle this request and return the content.

Answer (score 0):

if you use html to send your request to the server, the browser will follow the default behaviour of waiting for a response to your post command. If you want this to be treated differently, you might want to use AJAX as suggested. This way your browser will not reload the page, instead it will execute your code based on the server response.

Sometimes it's just a matter of disabling normal event browser behaviour like in [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) in jquery.

If your question is different please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to request your server to let it know you want to fetch some data whenever a user opens a folder on its browser.

This operation is asynchronous and you definitely don't want your user's browser to refresh each time the server sends new data.

You could start implementing something like the following on a client-side script :

```
function fetchData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       alert(this.responseText);
      }
   };
  xhttp.open("GET", "api/fetch-folder-content", true);
     xhttp.send();
   }
```

Then, you'll have to write a route on the server (i.e., a fetch-folder-content GET route) and trigger the above function when you want to fetch fresh data from your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Axios for post request without refreshing.

Link is below:
https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32479770)